# Why using a common hash key with AWS DynamoDB is a bad thing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I need to have a way to have items ordered by timestamp, so I am considering using a common hash key and unix timestamp as the range key.

According to the FAQ:

```
When storing data, Amazon DynamoDB divides a table into multiple partitions and 
distributes the data based on the hash key element of the primary key. The provisioned 
throughput associated with a table is also divided among the partitions; each 
partition's throughput is managed independently based on the quota allotted to it. 
There is no sharing of provisioned throughput across partitions.
```

As I am using a common hash key, then there will be no uneven load distribution - since all the load will goes into a single partition.

So when I provision `100 write` to this partition, all the capacity will be used, then I suppose it is a good thing as  capacity is not being wasted?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, think of DynamoDB as you would a hashmap. Think of how a hashmap performs when many items have the same hashcode/key.

Answer (score 8):

You provision writes and reads to a DynamoDB table, not a partition. Your capacity is spread/shared across the partitions, but each partition also has a fixed rate limit because of the underlying hardware.

By using a single hash key, you will have a fixed limit on how many reads and writes you can actually perform on the table, regardless of how many you are provisioning and paying for.

You can't scale it above that limit as dynamodb can't further partition your table to parallelize load processing, one of the primary ways AWS scales the system as your provision numbers increase.

It's possible you won't hit that limit at first, but Amazon recommends against this approach because Amazon wants you to use AWS in ways that will scale.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 1. Are there any limit on a single partition, e.g. max 2TB, max 1K write can be provisioned? Because sometimes, this limit might be ok for most users (not everyone need to be Google scale) 2. Another question is how hashing work on multiple partition, e.g. if I provision 10 write, and my hash key 1 to 10, so they will be in 10 partitions?

Comment: I doubt Amazon would share information like this as they can change how it works even for a single DynamoDB table.  For example, the might scale part way vertically by launching different instance types and then add in horizontal scaling by partitioning.  The horizontal scaling could be unlimited by making partitions smaller and smaller.  The guideline is simply to spread your key space out so that they can scale effectively to any provisioned limit.

Comment: Did any of you guys find a better solution than a single hash key? We are facing the same issue and wondered if you solved it in the mean time.

Comment: All of this information is in the documentation. A single partition is limited to 10 GB and 1000 read/write throughput units.

Comment: @Collin: 3000 read + 1000 write see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Comment: @Collin 10GB limit is only for table with any local secondary index. None without any local secondary index.

Comment: @pandora2000 From the docs: "A single partition can hold approximately 10 GB of data, and can support a maximum of 3,000 read capacity units or 1,000 write capacity units."

Answer (score 7):

A common trick in your case is to have

- `hash_key=%Y-%m-%d` (day timestamp)
- `range_key=iso-8601_timestamp+uuid`

This way your data is split accross partitions by day (assuming a quite even load from one day to another), but the range key allows for very fine `query` calls with a `BETWEEN` condition.
The `uuid` part is here to differentiate records that would have been insterted at (exactly) the same time.

Comment: This is actually exactly what the dynamodb documentation says not to do. You'll end up only writing to the partition corresponding to the current day, but your provisioned write throughput will be spread across all partitions.

Comment: Sure. it's a "solution" for query time but suboptimal for write time. Do you have something better in mind ?

Comment: The dynamodb documentation explicitly addresses time-series data: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns

Comment: you mean the part where they advocate for a table per, say, month ? (and updating r/w capacity over time as older data is no longer written and seldom read)